# Can jenkins be use with pipeline and parallel steps?

Tags: jenkins, parallel-processing

I have an application that I want to build for Ubuntu 32 bits, 64 bits. There is a second application that needs to be build on Windows.

So, I would like to know what is the best setup to do this.
Then the Mega-job starts:

1. The 32 bits and 64 bits and windows slave machine pull from SVN source control
2. The two Ubuntu machines starts building simultaneously App1 while the windows builds the windows App2 application
3. Once those 3 jobs are completed, unit tests are run on each machine
4. One everything is complete on all servers, produced binaries are pulled and published on an FTP server for the public to download/

So, my questions are:

- Should I use build pipeline ?
- Should I have multislaves ?
- Should I have 2 or 3 jobs ?
- How do I tell one job to go on one specific host to build ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add "Label expression" to a job. Here you can put the name of the slave where you want to job to run on.

Another option is to add Labels to a slave as well. 
Example

- Slave1 labels: Lunix, x64, x32
- Slave2 labels: Windows, x32
- Slave3 labels: Windows, x64
- Job1 labels: Linux, x64 -> Will run on Slave1
- Job2 labels: Windows, x32 -> Will run on Slave2
- Job3 labels: Windows -> Will run on either Slave2 or Slave3